# Why the method getResource result are different in java8 and java11

Tags: java, java-8, resources, java-11

## getResource difference

github:[resource difference](https://github.com/topsoft-support/resource-difference)

I found the result of method `getResource` run with java8 and java11 is not the same.

the maven project `t01` run with `java8` and the maven project `t02` run with `java11`

**The resource struct**

> ```
> resources
>   - dir
>       b.txt
>   a.txt
> ```

### t01(jdk8)

code

```java
System.out.println("-----------------0:");
System.out.println(MainTest.class.getResource(""));
System.out.println(MainTest.class.getResource("/"));
System.out.println(MainTest.class.getClassLoader().getResource(""));
System.out.println(MainTest.class.getClassLoader().getResource("/"));//should be null

System.out.println("-----------------1:");
System.out.println(MainTest.class.getResource("/a.txt"));
System.out.println(MainTest.class.getClassLoader().getResource("a.txt"));
System.out.println("-----------------2:");
System.out.println(MainTest.class.getResource("/dir/b.txt"));
System.out.println(MainTest.class.getClassLoader().getResource("dir/b.txt"));
```

result

```sh
-----------------0:
file:/D:/dev/workspace/test/t01/target/classes/top/topsoft/test/
file:/D:/dev/workspace/test/t01/target/classes/
file:/D:/dev/workspace/test/t01/target/classes/
null
-----------------1:
file:/D:/dev/workspace/test/t01/target/classes/a.txt
file:/D:/dev/workspace/test/t01/target/classes/a.txt
-----------------2:
file:/D:/dev/workspace/test/t01/target/classes/dir/b.txt
file:/D:/dev/workspace/test/t01/target/classes/dir/b.txt
```

### t02(jdk11)

code

```java
System.out.println("-----------------0:");
System.out.println(MainTest.class.getResource(""));
System.out.println(MainTest.class.getResource("/"));
System.out.println(MainTest.class.getClassLoader().getResource(""));
System.out.println(MainTest.class.getClassLoader().getResource("/"));//should be null

System.out.println("-----------------1:");
System.out.println(MainTest.class.getResource("/a.txt"));
System.out.println(MainTest.class.getClassLoader().getResource("a.txt"));
System.out.println("-----------------2:");
System.out.println(MainTest.class.getResource("/dir/b.txt"));
System.out.println(MainTest.class.getClassLoader().getResource("dir/b.txt"));
```

result

```sh
-----------------0:
file:/D:/dev/workspace/test/t02/target/classes/top/topsoft/test/
null
null
null
-----------------1:
file:/D:/dev/workspace/test/t02/target/classes/a.txt
file:/D:/dev/workspace/test/t02/target/classes/a.txt
-----------------2:
file:/D:/dev/workspace/test/t02/target/classes/dir/b.txt
null
```

The project `t01` result to be the same as I expected.

But the project `t02` result beyond my expectations.

`MainTest.class.getResource("/")`

`MainTest.class.getClassLoader().getResource("")`

`MainTest.class.getClassLoader().getResource("dir/b.txt")`

Why print null?

You can try it with the [github](https://github.com/topsoft-support/resource-difference) repository.

Comment: What’s the point of posting the code twice? Just to waste every reader’s time by letting them check whether there are difference in these two code fragments? Besides that, when you are actively using modules, you should include that information in the question (with details about how the module is declared), instead of letting readers infer this from your answer.

Comment: @Holger At the beginning, I didn’t know that this difference was caused by modularization. When this difference appeared, I had no clue. First of all, whether it is caused by my local environment is excluded,After all, I just started to use java11, and I didn’t know much about modularization. Later I learned that it was caused by module resource location

Comment: A module-info doesn’t spuriously appear in your project. You must have added it yourself, so you should have been aware that you were using modules and not just running the unmodified code under Java 11.

Answer (score 0):

Run in java11 must has the `module-info.java`,if the `module-info.java` doesn't exist ,it will be run with no module,the result will be same to run in java8